# What is the inertial heliocentric reference system used by NASA JPL to calculate the ephemerides of Near Earth Objects?

Tags: nasa, jpl-horizons, ephemeris, frames, near-earth-object

I'm using the website of NASA JPL Horizon system at this link [Small-Body Database Query](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_query.html)
to download a database of orbital elements for NEOs (asteroids and comets).

Although I checked the Horizons System manual at this link [Horizon System manual](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#search), I cannot understand what is the heliocentric inertial reference frame used to compute these data.

Can you help me?

Comment: I believe it is using the J2000 frame (Earth equatorial, or Earth Mean Equator EME2000) judging from clicking on Ceres it shows the reference frame: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?des=1

Comment: The frame used to numerically *calculate* the solar system ephemerides themselves, i.e. the massive bodies like the Sun, planets, their moons, and large asteroids can be read about in [The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/abd414) and the orbits of the lower mass objects like the rest of the comets and asteroids in the Small Body Database will be propagated using such an ephemeris. But I think you are asking what system they use to *provide* the small body ephemerides, not to initially calculate them?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @uhoh. The point is: Which reference system should I refer to when reading the orbital elements (semi-major axis, eccentricity, inclination, and so on) that I download at the first link provided in the question?

Comment: So, do I assume that the data are referred to `heliocentric IAU76/J2000 ecliptic` reference frame?